# Django application deployed at suburl, redirect to home page after login

Tags: python, django, apache

I have my page deployed at `http://example.com`. I also have my django application deployed at `http://example.com/djangoapp`.

I'm using `Apache 2.2` with this configuration (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`): `WSGIPythonPath /home/brian/djangoprojects/djangoapp`.

I also added the line `WSGIScriptAlias /djangoapp /home/brian/djangoprojects/djangoapp/djangoapp/wsgi.py` to the default `Apache Virtual Host` file and it works really nice.

However, after logging in, my application redirects me to `http://example.com/` instead of `http://example.com/djangoapp/homeit`.

Here's my `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from djangoapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_page, name="logout"),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name="login"),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name="register"),
    url(r'^register/success/$', views.register_success, name="register_success"),
    url(r'^homeit/$', views.homeit, name="homeit"),
]
```

Here's my `views.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from djangoapp.forms import RegistrationForm


@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('register_success'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form
    })

    return render_to_response(
        'registration/register.html',
        variables,
    )


def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response('registration/success.html')


def logout_page(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))


@login_required
def homeit(request):
    return render_to_response(('home.html', {'user': request.user}))
```

My settings file, `settings.py`:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/djangoapp/accounts/login/'
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SUB_SITE = "/djangoapp"
```

And finally, the login page which I'm using to log in:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block head %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
        <table border="0">
            <tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td>{{ form.username }}</td></tr>
            <tr><th><label for="id_password">Password:</label></th><td>{{ form.password }}</td></tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url "homeit" %}" />
    </form>
    <a href="{% url "register" %}">Register</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Quick read

Method to solve this:

- Add `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/djangoapp/homeit'` in settings.py
- Change your `urls.py` line `9` to `url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'extra_context': {'next':'/djangoapp/homeit'}}),`

---

### Explanation

Check for the documentation of django.contrib.auth.views.login present [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login)

The code for `def login` is as follows:

```
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
          redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
          authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
          current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    Displays the login form and handles the login action.
    """
    redirect_to = request.POST.get(redirect_field_name,
                                   request.GET.get(redirect_field_name, ''))

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = authentication_form(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # Ensure the user-originating redirection url is safe.
            if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=request.get_host()):
                redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

            # Okay, security check complete. Log the user in.
            auth_login(request, form.get_user())

            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    else:
        form = authentication_form(request)

    current_site = get_current_site(request)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)

    if current_app is not None:
        request.current_app = current_app

    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context)
```

What is happening:

- `django.contrib.auth.views.login` takes `redirect_field_name` and redirect accordingly
- Default value of `redirect_field_name` is `next`.
- Currently as you aren't passing anything as `next` parameter, it is making `redirect_to = ''` automatically.
- `HttpResponseRedirect` is being called as `HttpResponseRedirect('')`
- Thus it end up redirecting to your homepage, and not `/djangoapp`.

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake in my question. I would like to be redirected to `http://example.com/djangoapp/homeit` after logging in (updated my question). However, your answer will work in this case too, right?

Comment: Yes, it would work in that case too. Just change `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` and `next` accordingly wherever you wish to redirect (absolute paths). Have also updated the answer, check it out.. :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm checking your solution right now, did everything you wrote, but now I have something like this: `NameError at / name 'REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME' is not defined` when trying to browse `http://example.com/djangoapp`. Could it be the uppercase issue?

Comment: You just added, `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` and `extra_context` parameter, right ? `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME` is not part of answer, it was the explanation, you don't need to add this `login` function.

Comment: Just follow those 2 steps under `Quick read` heading, and ignore `Explanation` part. Tell if error is still coming...

Comment: Did it, and it didn't work out. Here's my `views.py` file: http://pastie.org/private/gvpjajz8p9ydmbjdyevqcg, here's my `urls.py` file: http://pastie.org/private/kuzuzqw4vteeigv1sgpg, here's my `settings.py` file: http://pastie.org/private/hnsjvfjoyk2j8969iyo9ua, here's my project structure: http://pastie.org/private/wegi8ywevqjc9edalexhig

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88918/discussion-between-skbly7-and-brian-brown).